# Eslint is unstable in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, vscode-extensions

I am using VS code and eslint extension.

Sometimes eslint is crashed with following error:

```
(node:1615011) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 257)
(node:1615011) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unhandled method eslint/confirmESLintExecution
    at /home/desktop/.vscode-server/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.1.14/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:53829
    at /home/desktop/.vscode-server/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.1.14/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:54123
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/desktop/.vscode-server/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.1.14/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:54488)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
(node:1615011) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 258)
```

Why? What is frong and how can I fix it?

Eslint extension:
2.1.14

VSCODE:

```
Version: 1.52.1 (user setup)
Commit: ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523
Date: 2020-12-16T16:34:46.910Z
Electron: 9.3.5
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue raised on the official GitHub repo regarding this, you can follow up there

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1156